# How to insert additional data into mysql while using implode

Tags: php, mysql, csv, insert

here is the code:

```
    if (($handle = fopen($source_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $columns = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",");
    foreach ($columns as &$column) {
        $column = str_replace(".","",$column);
    }
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        while(count($data) < count($columns)) {
            array_push($data, NULL);
        }
        $c = count($data);
        for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
            $data[$i] = "'{$data[$i]}'";
        }

        $sql[] = '(' . implode(',',$data) . ','.$_POST[group].')';
    }
            $sql = implode(',',$sql);

    $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (".mysql_real_escape_string(implode(",",$columns)).",Custgroup,user_id) VALUES " 
                      . $sql . "\n";
    mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error());

    fclose($handle);
      }
     }
```

If my csv file is:

lastname,firstname,gender

bob,ah,male

So now the query will be :  `INSERT INTO mytable (lastname,firstname,gender) VALUES ('bob','ah','male')`.
But how if I want to insert extra data into mysql together with the data in csv file?
Such as I have a value $_POST['group'] = 'family' and $_POST['user_id'] = '10', so I tried:

```
$sql[] = '(' . implode(',',$data) . ','.$_POST[group].','.$_POST[user_id].')';

$query = "INSERT INTO $target_table (".mysql_real_escape_string(implode(",",$columns)).",custgroup,user_id) VALUES " 
                      . implode(',',$sql) . "\n";
```

But in the query it will become :  `INSERT INTO mytable (lastname,firstname,gender,custgroup,user_id) VALUES ('bob','ah','male',family,10)`.
It didn't have single quote , so I have error to insert the record.Can I know how to solve this problem?

Comment: what's the point in doing mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $columns))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$sql[] = '(' . implode(',', $data) . ", '" . $_POST['group'] . "'," . $_POST['user_id'] . ')';

$query = "INSERT INTO $target_table (" . mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $columns)) . ',custgroup,user_id) VALUES ' . implode(',', $sql);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much.Now the query is:
INSERT INTO UserAddedRecord (lastname,firstname,cell,custgroup,user_id) VALUES ('Last','First','042819679', 'Family',1)

Comment: what's the point in doing `mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $columns))`?

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of readability you might consider the following :

```
$sql = sprintf("(%s,'%s',%d)",
    implode(',', $data),
    $_POST['group'],
    $_POST['user_id']
);
```

which gives you more flexibility and understanding in what your code actually performs.